# Copying Internal Tables in ABAP

Tags: abap

Error in code.

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZSUBROUTINE_TABLES
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT  zsubroutine_tables.
TYPES : BEGIN OF line_type,
          eno(3) TYPE n,
          ename(30) TYPE c,
          esal TYPE i,
        END OF line_type.

DATA itab TYPE line_type OCCURS 10 WITH HEADER LINE.
DATA jtab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF line_type.
**"DATA jtab TYPE line_type OCCURS 10 WITH HEADER LINE.**

PERFORM fill TABLES itab.
jtab = itab[].
PERFORM output TABLES jtab.


*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  fill
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*      -->P_ITAB     text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM fill TABLES p_itab LIKE itab[].
  p_itab-eno = '14'.
  p_itab-ename = 'Aman'.
  p_itab-esal = 3000.
  APPEND p_itab.

  p_itab-eno = '142'.
  p_itab-ename = 'Raman'.
  p_itab-esal = 5000.
  APPEND p_itab.
ENDFORM.                    "fill

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  output
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*      -->P_JTAB     text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM output TABLES p_jtab LIKE jtab[].
  LOOP AT p_jtab.
    WRITE : / p_jtab-eno, p_jtab-ename, p_jtab-esal.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDFORM.                    "output
```

The code in bold if uncommented raises error, why.
In the commented code, Both itab and jtab are declared in a similar way.
Error: The type of "ITAB" cannot be converted to the type of "JTAB".

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is far from a minimal example - it contains a lot of stuff that is not needed to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the two definitions of JTAB are different in the sense that the commented one has a header line while the other one has not. Because ITAB[] also has no header line the assignment of ITAB[] to JTAB will only work when JTAB has no header line. If you want to use the definition of JTAB with the header line you will need to assign ITAB directly to JTAB, no need for the hooked brackets.

Comment: The following modification will work. jtab[] = itab[]. Thanks.